# How to write conditional comment for non IE browsers?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, conditional-comments

I don't want to use a couple of javascript plugins for IE 6/7. 
But I want to use them for all other browsers.

How can I do it?
Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia article on conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) (modified to fit your version requirements):

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]><!-->
<p>This code displays on non-IE browsers and on IE 8 or higher.</p>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

The weird markup in the first line serves to make the markup standards compliant.

Comment: Is there a way to make the conditional comment for non IE browsers validate with https://validator.w3.org/ ? If using this all except IE or variations of conditional comment it it will throw the bogus comment error on the closing tags. Is there a way to avoid that validation error?

Comment: Indeed there is. [www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200511/valid_downlevelrevealed_conditional_comments/](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200511/valid_downlevelrevealed_conditional_comments/)

Comment: And I've posted [a question/answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132856/target-css-only-to-certain-ie-versions-and-non-ie-browsers/) with more detailed info.

Answer (score 6):

Your question would be better phrased as "Using conditional comments to exclude content from IE browsers" ;-)

Although CCs are most often used to provide additional content for IE, there is a variant that allows you to prevent IE from seeing content. With their usual arrogance, MS chose to call this "[downlevel-revealed conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx#dlrevealed)" (because all other browsers are worse than IE in their world).

Something like

```
<![if !IE]><p>You are not using Internet Explorer.</p><![endif]>
```

should be all you need.

Note that describing this as a "Conditional Comment" is another example of MS's strange use of words to mean exactly what they choose them to mean rather than what everybody else means: the above works because it isn't actually a comment, so all browsers other than IE just assume you made a hideous mistake in your HTML and carry on parsing the content within.

This also means it will probably fail badly in XHTML served with the application/xhtml+xml content type, but that's another story.

Comment: This targets anything else than IE, but what about IE > 7? Also, the markup isn't valid HTML, and thus the behavior in any non-IE browser is unspecified.

Comment: The condition can be <![if gt IE 7]> for IE 8 and up. As for the invalid markup and unspecified consequences: what else do you expect from Microsoft? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good resource for such things at: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/conditionalcompile.shtml

This in conjunction with the @_jscript_version variable should help you achieve the desired result. (You'll have to Google "Version Information (Windows Scripting - JScript)" for the JScript -> IE version lookup as I'm only allowed to embed one link as a new user.) :-(