# add css stylesheet for All Browsers Except Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, stylesheet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write conditional comment for non IE browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073605/how-to-write-conditional-comment-for-non-ie-browsers)

i have a stylesheet cause some problems with my website in internet explorer because it contain the a huge @fontface library .. can i load this stylesheet for all browser except internet explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, and the how is dependent upon what version of IE.

Explanation of how:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks.shtml

Comment: That page shows how to load a given CSS for different versions of IE.  It doesn't tell you how to NOT load a CSS file for just IE, but still load it for other browsers, which is what the OP was asking.

Comment: <!--[if !IE]>--><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="non-ie.css"><!--<![endif]-->