# HTML if not IE 8 or lower

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I tried using this syntax for IE8 or lower

```
<!--[if !lte IE 8]>
   //my code here
<![endif]-->
```

But it appears to comment out my code...is this code correct?

Comment: Do you mean to target other Internet Explorers, or other browsers?

Comment: I want to target every browser including IE9 only

Comment: You won't be able to target non-IE browsers, as they don't understand conditional comments. For IE >= 8, I think the syntax is `gte`

Comment: Uh, [Pekka...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1073639/82548). It's convoluted syntax, but it can be done. And to target IE <= 8 (which your question reads like you're trying) leave off the `!` and that should work as-is. For `gte`: `<!--[if gte IE 8]>` (but this only includes IE 8 and 9, since MS dropped conditional comments in IE 10.

Comment: How would that look? can you put it in an answer please

Comment: I am looking to exclude IE and lower, not IE9 and other broswers from this code....would I use this `<!--[if gte IE8]>` that would work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is valid syntax, but it does work in my case, so I'll post it here:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

This will target IE>=9 and other browsers, and IE<9 will ignore the content.

Comment: what about if >= IE9 or all other browsers? (all browsers except <IE9)?

Comment: @PatrickKeane From my answer: "This will target IE>=9 and other browsers, and IE<9 will ignore the content."

Answer (score 2):

With this condition the script will be loaded on IE10+ and any other browser that's not IE.

```
 <!--[if (gt IE 8)|!(IE)]><!-->

    <!-- put script here -->

 <!--<![endif]-->
```